# Laravel - How to catch all exceptions in Laravel Application and prevent users from seeing exceptions

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project I have tried to prevent users from seeing any code bugs in the Production environment but yet the bugs still appear.

For instance, I have taken care of all server errors: 404,500 etc.
Also in my controllers I have something like:

```
try {
    Session::flash('success', 'Staff is created successfully');
    return redirect()->route('employees.index');
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    DB::rollback();

    Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
    return redirect()->route('employees.index');
}
```

But I still see:

> Argument 2 passed to with() must be callable or null, object given

How do I prevent seeing any bug at all, but rather customized messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control laravel exceptions in exception handler located under `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

specifically  `render` method is responsible for checking exception render type based on instance of the exception itself. To mute the exceptions simply tweak the render method:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    /*Log exception somewhere or do whatever you want but prevent 
    default laravel render by commenting render below */

    //return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

even tho this is not good approach to silent errors, a better one would be to simply set `.env` parameters to not report any errors:

in your `.env` set `APP_DEBUG` to false:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:hufIiGav1fOzia1urm5Ik06Xa2NOEYMtP7mW0vE1tmw=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Comment: I have already done this:      in your .env set APP_DEBUG to false:

Comment: yeah then try to mute them in exception handler if you wish to do that way!

Comment: How? Can you give example?  Thanks

Comment: I already gave you the answer above go to: `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` and comment this line : `//return parent::render($request, $exception);`